# Check if the sequence converges?

Tags: analysis

Given the sequence $$\frac{1+2+...+n}{n+2}-\frac{n}{2}$$
I am asked to check if it converges. How can I do this? One way is to check if the sequence is bounded and monotonic, right? But how could we see if the sequence is monotonic?

Comment: Find a closed formula for $1+2+\dotsb + n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you mean that I have to write this as a sum?

Comment: No, I mean a short expression that is easier to manipulate than the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerator can be written as $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ (that's the closed formula Daniel is hinting at) and so if you combine the fractions into one, you get a numerator of $-n$ and a denominator of $2(n+2)$ Taking the limit for $n$ to inf gives -0.5

Comment: With this way we find the limit without having shown that the sequence converges, right? To do it with the other way, to show that it's bounded and monotonic, is the following correct? (By writing it as you said, we have $\frac{-n}{2(n+2)}$
$$\frac{-n-1}{2(n+3)}-\frac{-n}{2(n+2)}=-(\frac{n+1}{2(n+3)}+\frac{n}{2(n+2)})=- \frac{(n+1)(n+2)+n(n+3)}{2(n+2)(n+3)} \leq 0$$
$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)+n(n+3)}{2(n+2)(n+3)}$ is positive and with the $-$ it's negative. So the sequence is decreasing.

Comment: Yes, and when you take the derivative of the resulting term, you can see that it is decreasing with -0.5 as the limit. You did do a typo, it's $n+2$ not $n+3$

Comment: But at the first term of the difference we take $n+1$, so it gets $2((n+1)+2)=2(n+3)$, or am I wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar after putting $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ in the numerator, I made common denominators and combined the numerators. The common denominator is $2n+2$ and the new numerator turns out to be just $-n$

Answer (score 1):

If you name $u_n$ a term of the sequence, you can check the sign of $u_{n+1}-u_n$, if the sign is always negative (resp. positive), the sequence is decreasing (resp. increasing).

Comment: But how can  find this difference? $u_{n+1}-u_n=\frac{1+2+...+n+(n+1)}{n+3}-\frac{n+1}{2}-\frac{1+2+...+n}{n+2} + \frac{n}{2} $.How can I continue?

Comment: Look at the others answers and find another way to write $u_n$ (actually they gave it to you).